# Error: "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A0046 (CTL_E_PERMISSIONDENIED)" en VB.net

Tags: vb.net, .net

diseñe una aplicacion en windows form la cual genera un archivo de texto cada 5 min, y esta operando en una maquina en donde tiene instalado un Windows Service que se encarga de revisar el archivo que esta generando esta aplicacion, al detectar un cambio en el archivo, el lo lee y recupera los datos que cambiaron. Todo funcionaba bien pero ayer me salio este error (ya que coloque en el codigo un try-catch):  "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A0046 (CTL_E_PERMISSIONDENIED)" y este mensaje "the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process". Comprendo que ocurre esto, porque en el mismo instante que estoy sobreescribiendo el archivo la aplicacion, el windows service esta revisando para saber si ocurrio un cambio, pero no se como arreglar este error en la aplicacion ya que no puedo tocar ni modificar el windows service, por favor ayuda.
Aqui dejo el codigo de la aplicacion de windows:

```
    Public Class Module1

    Private Sub Main
    Dim Frecuencia() As String
    Dim Tiempo As Integer
    Dim tiempo_ejecucion As Date
    dim archive_name as string


    ruta = "C:\Users\Developer\Documents"
    Tiempo = 30000 'se ejecuta para 5 min'
    Timer5.Enabled = True
    Timer5.Interval = Tiempo 

    End Sub

 Private Sub Timer5_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer5.Tick

     Randomize()

     Dim valor_random As Double
     Dim Archivo As Object
     Dim Instruccion As Object

     Try

     valor_random = (Rnd() * 0.1)
     valor_random = FormatNumber(initialweight, 2)
     Instruccion = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Archivo=Instruccion.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\Developer\Documents\prueba.txt", True)

    Archivo.writeline(valor_random)
    Archivo.writeline(valor_random)
    Archivo.writeline(valor_random)
    Archivo.writeline(valor_random)
    Archivo.writeline(valor_random)
    Archivo.writeline(valor_random)
    Archivo.close()


        Catch x As Exception
            MsgBox("error: " & x.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    End Class
```

Asi es el codigo, ¿donde estara el error?

Comment: No tienes error en el código, lo que pasa que el archivo está ocupado por otra aplicación y al intentar sobreescribirlo te da el error Permision Denied como comentas. Si el servicio despues de comprobar el archivo lo cierra podrías implementar un sistema de TimeOut, que vaya en bucle probando de guardar el archivo hasta N intentos, y si no ha podido despues de los intntos que le hayas puesto entonces te salte el error.

Comment: @Marc no se mucho del uso del TimeOut, ni como hacerlo en codigo, investigue pero no quede muy claro, como seria? y en que momento deberia reiniciar el contador?

Comment: Te escribo una respuesta con un simple TimeOut a ver si te sirve.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que el momento en que vas a guardar el archivo se está usando por otro proceso en ese mismo instante. Si el proceso que lo está ejecutando cierra el archivo después de tratarlo puedes aplicar un sistema de intentos para que intente X veces de guardar el archivo, expongo un ejemplo a continuación:

```
Try

    valor_random = (Rnd() * 0.1)
    valor_random = FormatNumber(initialweight, 2)
    Instruccion = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim intentos As Integer = 0;
    Dim success As Boolean = False

    While intentos <= 10 Or success = False

        Try
            Archivo=Instruccion.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\Developer\Documents\prueba.txt", True)
            Archivo.writeline(valor_random)
            Archivo.writeline(valor_random)
            Archivo.writeline(valor_random)
            Archivo.writeline(valor_random)
            Archivo.writeline(valor_random)
            Archivo.writeline(valor_random)
            Archivo.close()

            success = True
        Catch e As Exception
            Thread.Sleep(5000); 'Esperamos 5 segundos para que vuelva a hacer Loop
        End Try

        intentos += 1
    End While

    If intentos = 10 Then
        Throw New System.Exception("TimeOut.")
    End If

    Catch x As Exception
        MsgBox("error: " & x.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```